# How to add exception handling to my before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `before_action` method like this:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(:id => session[:id])
end
```

And I call a method like this:

```
def get_food user
  food = Food.find(:id => user.id)
end
```

This is fine, but I want to add exception handling.

When the user is nil I want to use `@current_user`:

```
def get_food user
  food = Food.find(if user is nil i want to use @current_user.id)
end
```

Of course, I can write it like this:

```
def get_food user
  if user.nil?
    food = Food.find(@current_user.id)
  else
    food = Food.find(user.id)    
end
```

Or, is this the best way?

```
def get_food user
  food = Food.find(user == nil? @current_user.id : user.id)
end
```

I'm curious is there a better way than adding a simple `if` statement inside the param?

Comment: I would leave it as you've written it, it's cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: @japed that is fine. when this is the only feature. in my real app. there are so many nil checking if statement inside :(. i want to throw it away the dirty part :(

Comment: What is `user` in your method - is it a local variable?  If so where is it defined?  Is it a method?  If so, on what?

Comment: I prefer `present?`, so taking your code it'd be `food = Food.find(user.present? ? user.id : @current_user.id)`

Comment: Please take the time to use capitalization and formatting when writing your question. Doing so makes it easier to read and understand what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest one lines I can think of are something like this:

```
Food.find((user || current_user).id)
Food.find(user.try(:id) || current_user.id)
Food.find(user ? user.id : current_user.id)
```

Not sure if this is really an impovement in readability. I would prefer something like this:

```
def get_food(user)
  user ||= current_user
  Food.find(user.id)
end
```

Comment: isn't this (user || current_user) only checks boolean it exist or not?

Comment: No, it returns the first value that is not `false` or not `nil`.

Comment: I would have done the same: `user ||= current_user` and then `Food.find(user.id)`. +1

Comment: @Canna : `(user || current_user)` checks and return first value if first value is truthy, i.e.: not false or nil, otherwise returns the next value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to make it one line:

```
user ? Food.find(user.id) :  Food.find(@current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `arrays`

```
food = Food.where(id: [@current_user.try(:id),user.id]).first
```

Comment: You may end up getting an undesirable record in case, i.e. it will break with undefined method `id` for `nilClass` when user `nil`, and will give `current_user.id`'s food record if user is not nil. Either ways, it won't produce the result you'd expect.

Comment: you mean if `user` is also `nil` ?

Comment: 1: user is nil: calling `user.id` will throw error. 2: user is not `nil`: [current_user.id, user.id] #=> [1, 2], which means always get the current_user's food association.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
food = Food.find(user.nil? ? @current_user.id : user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about default parameters?

```
def get_food(user = @current_user)
  food = Food.find(user.id)
end
```

It will work if you call it without the parameter

```
something.get_food # notice the method is called with no params
```

If you want it working also if you pass `nil`, you should also add:

```
def get_food(user = @current_user)
  food = Food.find((user || @current_user).id)
end
```

However is strange that foods and users have the same ids...
Maybe the correct query is:

```
food = Food.find_by_user_id((user || @current_user).id)
```

or, if users have more than just one food:

```
foods = Food.where(user: (user || @current_user)) # rails 4, :user => (user || @current_user) for rails 3
```

Comment: This won't work!! Considering passed argument is `user` where user in `nil`. This will work only when `get_food` is called without an argument.

Comment: Of course, which I thought was the point.
If you want it works even when you manually pass nil as parameter, then @spickermann first solution is the best one.

Comment: How can that be a point when OP wants a method where he/she can pass an argument? And if it's nil then it should use `current_user` instead. Your solution doesn't solve the problem, it introduces one.

Comment: Not sure about this without knowing the context where this function will be used, but yes, I got your point, so let me change the answer  to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Food.find(user.id rescue @current_user.id)
```

Comment: Don't do this. If `user` is nil it will behave as expected. If `user` exists but, for some reason, doesn't have an `id` method, or the `id` method blows up, it will not do the right thing which would be to raise an exception saying so. Instead, it will silently pass `@current_user.id`, making a very hard to diagnose bug.

Comment: Fully agree, it's not how I'd do it. But I was responding to the original question as it was worded.

Comment: "as it was worded" has to be carefully handled. Too often people ask questions assuming something has to be done a certain way often out of ignorance or naivety, and that paints them into a corner badly. When we see that we can let them continue in the dark and help them fix one problem, or we can show them a better way that will help them avoid the corner entirely. So, instead of only answering the question, answer it, then show the right way, or at least a better way. The difference helps them, and it also shows your ability to teach, which is good for us all.